# Shared child component between different parent component not rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 2 component(/Dashboard and /WeeklyDashboard) and they have a common child component (/Linegraph).
when the route changes even though I am passing new props to the child component from the parent component, it doesn't update with the new data provided .Is there any way to solve the issue.I tried using componentDidUpdate but, it only gets called when page reloads not when the route is changing

App.js

```
render() {


return (
  <div className="Main">
    <div className="SearchGroup">
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <NavBar />
        <div>
       
      </div>
      </div>

    
    </div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/"  component={() => <Dashboard WeatherDetails={this.state.ResponseDetails} WeatherDetails2={this.state.ResponseDetails1} WeatherDetails3={this.state.ResponseDetails2} />} exact />
      <Route path="/Weekly"  component={() => <WeeklyDashboard/>} exact />
   
    </Switch>
  </div>
```

Dashboard.js

```
const HourlyTemp=this.props.WeatherDetails3;

 
return (
 
    <div className="Graph">
            <LineGraph HourlyTemp={HourlyTemp}/>
          </div>
);
```

LineGraph.js

```
import React from "react";


class LineGraph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    alert("hi");
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    for (var key in this.props.HourlyTemp) {
      if (key < 16) {
        var toStr = convert(this.props.HourlyTemp[key].dt).toString();
        var temp = {
          name: toStr,
          Temperature: this.props.HourlyTemp[key].temp,
        };

        data1.push(temp);
      }
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <LineChart
          width={800}
          height={400}
          data={data1}
          margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 30,
            left: 20,
            bottom: 5,
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="0 0" />
          <XAxis dataKey="name" />
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <Legend />
          <Line
            type="monotone"
            dataKey="Temperature"
            stroke="orange"
            activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
          />
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Temperature" stroke="orange" />
        </LineChart>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LineGraph;
```

WeeklyDashboard

```
function WeeklyDashboard(props) {
      var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
      return (
        <div style={{ margin: "auto", width: "80%" }}>
          <div className="WeeklyContainer">
            {a.map(function (x, key) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Weekly key={key} />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div style={{ margin: "auto", width: "fit-content" }}>
            <LineGraph key={"ss"} HourlyTemp={"ss"} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
        export default WeeklyDashboard;
```

Comment: Please, include the code of the component containing route configuration and both parent components. It will help us give you a better anwser.

Comment: Use setState when modifying the props?

Comment: You are not passing the values into your weeklydashboard

Comment: I am passing the data to line graph (HourlyTemp) from the weekly dashboard.But the issue is that the line graph component is not updating .

Comment: Yeah I was passing the wrong props

Comment: You're not passing any props to the WeeklyDashboard.js in the App.js while passing  the WeatherDetails to the Dashboard.js